# How can install ike (shrew soft vpn) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: vpn

How can I install ike package (shrew soft vpn)? I have tried with the command `suto apt install ike`, but it didn't work for me. The output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ike
```

I tried with deb package with the following command:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i ike-qtgui_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
```

But it didn't work:

```
Selecting previously unselected package ike-qtgui.
(Reading database ... 162541 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ike-qtgui_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ike-qtgui (2.2.1+dfsg-6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ike-qtgui:
 ike-qtgui depends on ike; however:
  Package ike is not installed.
 ike-qtgui depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1); however:
  Package libqtcore4 is not installed.
 ike-qtgui depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ike-qtgui (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ike-qtgui
```

Comment: I installed ShreVPN and I just run manually /usr/sbin/iked
(actually added it to /etc/rc.local)
# iked
ii : created ike socket 0.0.0.0:500
ii : created natt socket 0.0.0.0:4500
## : IKE Daemon, ver 2.2.1
## : Copyright 2013 Shrew Soft Inc.
## : This product linked OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

and after that my VPN works
I don't remember from where I installed iked, but it was not .deb - I think it came with shrew VPN

Comment: I downloaded it from here: [https://www.shrew.net/download/ike](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike)

it is old, but it works fine with my fortigate (problem that forticlient for linux does not have IPSec VPN)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install IKE software on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244258/how-to-install-ike-software-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/) and [How to download a software package with all dependencies and sub-dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033682/how-to-download-a-software-package-with-all-dependencies-and-sub-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

The `ike` packages were dropped from Debian after Stretch (Released June 2017).

Correspondingly, Ubuntu dropped `ike` packages after 18.04.

You can build `ike` from source instead: [Here's how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244258/how-to-install-ike-software-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Do you know another way to install this package?

Comment: Ubuntu  18.04 is supported for three more years. That would be the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, I have used it in Ubuntu 18.04, but after update to Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't work anymore. So I am looking for a way to install ike in Ubuntu 20.04. If you know an idea of how can I solve it, I will be very thankful.

Comment: I'm saying that your easy option is to go back to 18.04. You have a logic problem here: ike does not run on 20.04. Therefore, you must either use 18.04 or use a different VPN client. There is no easy magic "*click this button and it will start to work*" that we know of. Sorry to be the bearer of that bad news. If you have the skills you can try compiling ike for 20.04, but that seems a bit too much work for a mere VPN client.

Comment: Do you know why it has been dropped? Security reasons?

Comment: I do not know the specifics of this case. Packages are rarely dropped for "security reasons" though it does happen for egregiously vulnerable software. They usually get fixed instead. Most dropped packages are due to transitions (package was renamed/merged/split), or the package developer(s) abandoned the project and nobody cared enough to fork it and continue the work, it or the Debian packager lost interest and no community member cared enough about the package to adopt it.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to the same VPN I was previously accessing with the Shrewsoft client using options available to 20.04? I see I can create a new PPTN or OpenVPN connection, and I have a Shrewsoft .vpn config file. Not sure if these are compatible.

Comment: @Martyn the Question indicates that `ike` is required. This Answer points out that `ike` is not available in 20.04. So the answer is 'No'. This seems like a Shrewsoft support question.

Comment: For unbuntu 20.04 install instuctions see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244258/how-to-install-ike-software-on-ubuntu-20-04