# How to install IKE software on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, vpn

Is there a easy way to install this VPN client [IKE software](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike) over Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: What is the question by the way? If you already have answer - please create two parts  - the question and the answer with your findings and works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading some forum, I decide to recompile sources under Ubuntu 20.04 because this packet is out of maintenance until some years. The dependencies, packets and libraries were no longer installable in 20.04 LTS. I've fixed issue to old library and created a patch to apply at the last version of [source file](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike) (shrew soft iked and ikec). This procedure you will find here below and the patch file is in my [blog](https://sites.google.com/view/uptolinux).

Download the extract the sources.

```
wget https://www.shrew.net/download/ike/ike-2.2.1-release.tbz2
sudo tar jxpvf ike-2.2.1-release.tbz2
cd ike
```

Copy in this directory [ike.patch](https://sites.google.com/view/uptolinux) file.

```
patch -p1 < ike.patch
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libaudio-dev libcups2-dev  cmake libedit-dev g++
```

Now recompile with NO-GUI directive.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DQTGUI=NO -DETCDIR=/etc -DNATT=YES
make
sudo make install
sudo iked
```

Check if yourServer.vpn file is present under your "~/.ike/sites/" directory. If no copy it without .vpn extension (like this: ~/.ike/sites/yourServer)

```
ikec -r yourServer -a
```

If all goes well, you should see at the end

```
...

"ii : tunnel enabled"
```

I hope that can help someone.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing patch. I can confirm it works. I found a bit difficult to download the code and there's also a `dos2unix` to perform before applying the patch, so I created a github repo giving you all the credit (https://github.com/MaxChinni/ike-for-ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks Max. Next time I'll create a GitHub instead of simple blog too.

Comment: dude thanks i was dying inside with the patch not working.

Answer (score 7):

Following the above general instructions  and after googling some time, I found also the way to enable ShRew to run full, including GUI, on ubuntu 20+ / Debian 9+.

You can download the full software from https://mega.nz/file/4xV10IqZ#nmAJYGBJvdcI5jhp61DAIHhM4ILKg8x2hHYTpJD6eP4

Execute the script install_shrew.sh and VOILA!!!

Please, test and share (if you like) :)

Thanks to Kulfy for his good work

Comment: It works, but you need to change /home/[USERNAME]/ path in some make files.

Comment: also you need to install libssl-dev

Answer (score 4):

Another possible answer is using deb packages:

1. Add QT4 Repo:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
   sudo apt update
   ```

   Source: [How to Install Qt4 Libraries in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS | UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/install-qt4-ubuntu-20-04/)
2. Install dependencies:

   ```
   apt install cmake libssl-dev libedit-dev flex bison qt4-default qt4-qmake
   ```

   Source: [Forticlient IPSec VPN on Ubuntu Linux • lorenzo milesi](https://lorenzo.mile.si/forticlient-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu-linux/1103/)
3. Download old deb files (from bionic):

   - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libssl1.0.0
   - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ike
   - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/ike-qtgui

   Install the debs with `sudo dpkg -i <file.deb>` in the order:

   ```
   libssl1.0.0 
   ike
   ike-qtgui
   ```

   In my case (AMD64):

   ```
   mkdir ~/ikedebs
   cd ~/ikedebs
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ike/ike_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ike/ike-qtgui_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i ike_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i ike-qtgui_2.2.1+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
   ```

and voila!

Once installed, launch using

```
sudo iked
```

to start daemon.

for GUI:

```
qikea
```

Comment: works like a charm :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, also if you are like me, using it as a Forticlient VPN IPSEC alternative, you can see the configurations for it here: [link](https://sistemasyseguridad.wordpress.com/2017/01/29/contenido-destacado/) is in spanish but still can be understood with the pictures

Answer (score 1):

A friend make it compatible for ubuntu 22.04 and qt5

https://github.com/dolomighty/shrewsoft-ike

You must compile it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1246847)