# Connect to VPN in Ubuntu 20.04 without Shrewsoft VPN client

Tags: vpn

I've previously been connecting to our work VPN using Shrewsoft VPN client but it seems the [ike packages were dropped after Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231637/how-can-install-ike-shrew-soft-vpn-on-ubuntu-20-04). I've recently upgraded to 20.04 and hoping to keep it, but I need to get on this VPN.

If I try to create a new connection manually in 20.04, I have the options of PPTN and OpenVPN. I also have a .vpn config text file that has a load of settings for Shrewsoft VPN client. I can see the host/gateway and I know my username and password. Is it possible to connect to this VPN, or will I need to revert back to 18.04?

The .vpn file:

```
n:version:4
n:network-ike-port:500
n:network-mtu-size:1380
n:client-addr-auto:1
n:network-natt-port:4500
n:network-natt-rate:15
n:network-frag-size:540
n:network-dpd-enable:1
n:client-banner-enable:1
n:network-notify-enable:1
n:client-dns-used:1
n:client-dns-auto:1
n:client-dns-suffix-auto:1
n:client-splitdns-used:1
n:client-splitdns-auto:1
n:client-wins-used:1
n:client-wins-auto:1
n:phase1-dhgroup:5
n:phase1-life-secs:86400
n:phase1-life-kbytes:0
n:vendor-chkpt-enable:0
n:phase2-life-secs:3600
n:phase2-life-kbytes:0
n:policy-nailed:0
n:policy-list-auto:1
n:phase2-keylen:256
s:network-host:vpn.myworkdomain.com
...etc
```

Comment: does your vpn provider provide configuration files? end with an .ovpn extension, then in terminal  sudo nm-connection-editor, click the + add button, go to the end of the drop down box for import a saved vpn configuration, select your file  (maybe you could select your manual file there)  , put in user and passwd.        I am using Nordvpn and they now have a nordvpn terminal app, which for me has sped my speeds up enormously using udp. it also has a kill connection if vpn is lost, which is good seeing as protectvpn gnome addon is not something I can find anymore.