# Can't install vscode arm64

Tags: dpkg, raspberrypi, arm64

when i use `sudo dpkg -i code_1.58.2-1626300392_arm64.deb`

then

```
(Reading database ... 99048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.58.2-1626300392_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking code:arm64 (1.58.2-1626300392) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:arm64:
 code:arm64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.26).
 code:arm64 depends on apt.
 code:arm64 depends on libxkbfile1.
 code:arm64 depends on libsecret-1-0.
 code:arm64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.10.0).
 code:arm64 depends on libxss1.
 code:arm64 depends on libgbm1.

dpkg: error processing package code:arm64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.31.4-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code:arm64
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your package details do not align with any on-topic release system for this site*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a software package with all dependencies and sub-dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033682/how-to-download-a-software-package-with-all-dependencies-and-sub-dependencies)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg` cannot automatically handle dependencies. Use `apt` instead.

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.58.2-1626300392_arm64.deb
```

Alternatively, if you already installed it using `dpkg`, you can get the missing dependencies with

```
sudo apt install -f
```