# Offline Installation of Apache/2.4.54 on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, offline, apt-offline

I have tried installing Apache 2.4.56 from source. However, I want to install Apache/2.4.54 on Ubuntu18.04, offline(without accessing internet)
Is there any way to download apache2 and its dependencies onto Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual machine and install it.

I can see 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.25 is the latest installation candidate available for Ubuntu18.04. As higher versions have security fixes. I would like to go with installing Apache2.4.46 or higher.

Could you please suggest a procedure for successful offline installation of latest Apache2

Comment: You are aware that Ubuntu backports the security fixes to the supported version (eg. refer http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.29-1ubuntu4.25/changelog where you'll see many CVE fixes are backported)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a software package with all dependencies and sub-dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033682/how-to-download-a-software-package-with-all-dependencies-and-sub-dependencies)