# Problem installing the software

Tags: 22.04, deb

I downloaded the .deb file of several programs.  When I double click the file and open it with the software installer, I click install and after a few moments the window automatically closes and the software doesn't install.  I did this with several programs.  please guide me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)  and [How to download a software package with all dependencies and sub-dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033682/)